# py not recognizable, python is?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5

So, today I installed a Bot for a Discord server, yet the .bat to run said server wasn't picking up py.exe as an executable.. I was troubled, so I edited all reference of py.exe in said .bat to python.exe, and the .bat ran perfectly. Why doesn't windows recognize py.exe, but recognized python.exe? I have Python 3.5.2 installed.

Comment: do you have `py.exe` installed in C:\windows? what does `where py` return?

Comment: No given files were found in C:\ under py. Python is currently installed under C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32 , not sure if that helps.

Comment: this file is launcher to run the default version of python. You don't really need this. Maybe it's not installed in some cases / portable installs?

Comment: Well... Any use of py in cmd/bats dont work, only python.. I have no idea how that happened or how to fix it either.

Comment: I do have py.exe in C:\windows actually.

Comment: Ok, I simply copied py.exe from windows and pasted it into my Python35-32 folder.. and it recognizes it now. Which could mean that c:\windows isn't a path.. Woops.

Comment: I have Python 3.5.2 installed, using the Anacona3 installation, the there is no py.exe file. The closest thing to it is py.test.exe. Python in a command window starts with Python.exe. Why should it start with py.exe?

Comment: @RyanMaxwell, check in the environment variable editor that the system `PATH` value has `%SystemRoot%`, which adds the Windows directory. The interesting thing here is that `CreateProcess` doesn't require this. It always searches the application and system directories before searching `PATH`. But cmd.exe, which executes .bat files, implements all of its own `PATH` searching and requires the system directories to be listed in `PATH`.

Comment: py.exe is just a launcher, windows specific, no crucial need for it. Read here: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html